# Export button disappears when LinqPad query completes

Tags: linqpad

I'm using LinqPad 5.08.01, and want to export my results to a .csv file.

When the query is running, I see the Format and Export buttons at the right end of the bar between the code and results panes, but as soon as the query ends, and my results are displayed, both buttons disappear, and I am unable to export my data.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the data grid, and you'll see a pop-up menu with options to open in Excel, or export to Excel, csv or HTML.